# Which pure-blood families continue to exist?

Tags: harry-potter

Several pure-blood families feature in the Harry Potter series both in the books and in extended canon.

Of these families we know of several instances where the children (Wizards who were children or young adults during the books) have now had children of their own.

**Who are the children and are they pure-blood?**

**Who were the parents?**

**Were there any lineages that were ended during the events of the series?**

To name but a few pure-bloods we have all of the Weasley children, Draco Malfoy, Neville Longbottom, Luna Lovegood(I believe?), Crabbe, Goyle, Greengrass, Parkinson and Shacklebolt.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There’s a list [“The Sacred Twenty-Eight”](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sacred_Twenty-Eight), which supposedly lists all the pure-blood families in the land. We know this list isn’t complete (for example, the Potters are omitted), but it gives us somewhere to start.

#### Surviving to Harry’s year

On this list, we can identify several pure-blood families with children in Harry’s year (surviving families):

- Hannah **Abbott**
- Millicent **Bulstrode**
- Astoria and Daphne **Greengrass**
- Neville **Longbottom**
- Ernie **Macmillan**
- Draco **Malfoy**
- Marcus **Flint**
- Theodore **Nott**
- Pansy **Parkinson**
- Harry **Potter**
- More **Weasleys** than I care to list

These families may no longer be strictly pure-blood – for example, Harry is half-blood by Lily. However, the family names all survive.

All of these people are believed to have survived the Battle of Hogwarts, and so the family name continues. Several of the names are known to survive to the next generation (Potter, Malfoy and Weasley). We don’t know much about the extended families, so it’s possible that the families with no male heirs are soon to disappear.

#### Surviving beyond Harry’s year

Several family names survive, but only one is sure to be pure-blood:

- Harry and Ginny’s children continue the **Potter** name, but Harry’s half-blood status mean this is no longer a pure-blood family.
- Draco and Astoria’s son Scorpius continues the **Malfoy** line. They are both on the sacred twenty-eight, and the families have strong blood supremacist tendencies – Scorpius is pure-blood (perhaps one of the last truly pure-blood wizards)
- There are multiple children with the **Weasley** name, but I don’t think there are any spouses that we know are pure-blood. (The surnames we know don’t appear on the sacred twenty-eight, but that isn’t a guarantee.) Thus the name survives, perhaps not the blood purity.

#### Extinct or endangered

These are the families which have recently or will soon disappear:

- The **Blacks** – at the end of *Order of the Phoenix*, the last surviving member of this family is killed.
- The **Crouches** – the two remaining members of this family die in the course of *Goblet of Fire*.
- The **Gaunts** – the name died out sometime before *Half-Blood Prince*, and the last descendent was Tom Riddle. That family is well and truly squashed.
- Molly Weasley was the last person to have the name **Prewett**; the family survives although the name does not.

There are some families with no known children in Harry’s generation, and which are liable to disappear in the near future:

- A selection of Death Eater families: **Avery**, **Burke**, **Carrow**, **Fawley**, **Lestrange**, **Rosier**, **Rowle**, **Traver**, **Yaxley**
- Others: **Ollivander**, **Selwyn**, **Shacklebolt**, **Slughorn**

Comment: I'd +1 again if I could just for the 'extinct or endangered' heading - just imagining a picture of Shacklebolt's face on an 'endangered' list in an environmental official's office!

Answer (score 15):

We only have a few pure-blooded families, according to [HP Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizworld/blood-status-names.html):

- The Black Family (died out at the end of OP with Sirius' death)
- The Crouch Family (died out with the deaths of Barty Crouch Sr and Jr)
- The Gaunt Family who, as far as I can tell, died out according to the events we witness in HBP
- The Lestrange Family - it seems that they either died out or very soon will according to this note on the (forgive me) [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lestrange_family#cite_note-0)
- The Longbottom Family, continued by Neville (his [HP Lexicon page](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/neville.html) would indicate that we don't know that he has had any children)
- The Malfoy Family, continued by Malfoy's child Scorpius according to the [HP Lexicon page on Draco](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/draco.html)
- The Weasley Family, continued by quite a few children as seen in the below family tree by JR Rowling herself:
  [image]

So, to summarise and address the actual question, **the pure-blood families that continued to survive following the events of canon were**:

- [The Longbottoms](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/longbottom.html): the last child in that family that we know of is **Neville**, who *is* pure-blooded.  His parents were Alice and Frank Longbottom.
- [The Malfoys](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/malfoy.html): the last child in that family is **Scorpius** who *is* be pure-blooded; his parents are Draco Malfoy (pure blooded) and [Astoria Greengrass](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/a-z/g.html#astoria) (because at the end of DH it is noted that Scorpius is pure-blooded, we must assume that Greengrass is probably pure-blooded as well)
- [The Weasleys](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/weasley.html) are an interesting case, because we are uncertain about the blood-status of several of the spouses of the Weasley family members:

  - *Possibly* Fred Weasley II and Roxanne Weasley, who are the children of Angelina Weasley (nee Johnson) whose blood-status is unconfirmed, and George Weasley
  - *Possibly* Molly and Lucy Weasley, who are the daughters of Percy and Audrey Weasley (Audrey's blood-status is unknown)

Comment: Ah but, Malfoy did indeed marry and have a child. Ah the family tree features that nvm...

Comment: Would you mind editing to show which of the Weasley Grandchildren have a pure-blood status? I.e James, Albus and Lily would not.

Comment: @CandiedMango done!

Comment: @The Doc Neville married Hannah Abbott, but we don't know if they had children? Am I right? If they did they would be pure blood, but we don't know that they had any?

Comment: @ThruGog Correct on both counts: Neville and Hannah's children would be pure-blood (assuming that the Abbott's inclusion in the Sacred Twenty-Eight is accurate), and we don't know if they had any.

Comment: @ThruGog what alexwlchsn said

Comment: I'm confused about the 'd. 1997'. I don't remember the books naming any specific years for any of the events. (seemed to be set in a generic 'now'). Did I miss something?

Comment: @LindaJeanne It's never very obvious in the books but it is definite that Harry started Hogwarts in September 1991. It's quite convenient that book 1 started in '91 up to book 7 beginning in '97. It's confirmed that Harry was born in 1980.

Comment: Ah, the joys of converting school year dates to calendar dates: Didn't the Battle of Hogwarts (and thus Fred's death) occur in 1998?

Answer (score -1):

The Blacks really didn't die out because Narcissa is a black which means that that bloodline survived through Draco and Scorpius. They just don't go by the name black.

Comment: Although technically an answer, this feels more like an attempt to comment on the answers above